# Usage of RegEx in vb6

Tags: regex, vb6

I need to validate a string, which might contain alphanumeric as well as special character, where as I have to pass the one which has only Alpha chars (no numbers or any other special characters are allowed)

In a current method I use ASCII numbers to evaluate each character if its alpha or not. Is there any other efficient way to discover the presence of special characters or numbers in the string? Like can't we use **Like** or something to check once than going character by character?

```
For y = 2 To Len(sString)
    If Not ((Asc(Mid$((sString,y,1))>64 AND Asc(Mid$((sString,y,1))<91) OR _
    (Asc(Mid$((sString,y,1))>96 AND Asc(Mid$((sString,y,1))<123)) Then
        //Display an error msg
        Exit For
    End If
Next y
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are ignoring the *first* character? You are starting the `For` loop at `y = 2`

Comment: @MarkJ, yes because first character has some other limits..

Comment: anyways .. I had got the solution for this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in VB6. You have to add a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library to your project. You can then use the following:

```
Dim rex As RegExp
Set rex = New RegExp
rex.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z]"
If rex.Test(s) Then
    ' Display error message
End If
```

---

**When I originally answered this question, it was tagged as VB.NET; for future reference, my original .Net-based answer is retained below**

As you thought, this can be done with regular expressions (don't forget `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[^a-zA-Z]") Then
    ' Display error msg
End If
```

---

Also, the original code reads like VB6 code, not VB.NET. Here is a much more readable way to write the original non-regex code:

```
For Each ch As Char In someString
    If Not (ch >= "a"c AndAlso ch <= "z"c OrElse ch >= "A"c AndAlso ch <= "Z"c) Then
        ' Display error msg
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @Neil Knight: No, the regex matches non-alpha characters, so a match means the error message must be shown. The match is true if the string contains any invalid characters.

Comment: @infant programmer: your question was tagged `vb.net` when I answered it... I've added a VB6 answer as well.

Comment: @infant programmer: no problem. I hope the VB6 code I added will help you. :)

Comment: thanks :) yup working like gem :)
btw one question here. How to treat first character separately? I mean .. first character should be ALPHA and rest other chars can be alpha-numeric? I have found a work around by declaring two separated RegExps however.

Comment: @infant programmer: just use something like `"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$"` (in this case a match would indicate a valid value rather than invalid). See the regular expression reference for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2.aspx Also, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 8):

VBA has a native `Like` operator: its syntax is non-standard e.g. its multi-character wildcard is `*` and the NOT operator is `!`:

```
If sString Like "*[!A-Za-z]*" Then
  ' Display an error msg
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`

Code to check for non-alpha characters:

```
'Prepare a regular expression object
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As Match
Dim matchesFound As Boolean

Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z]+"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute("abc123def#$%")
matchesFound = myMatches.Count > 0
```

Check out [How To Use Regular Expressions in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802) at Microsoft Support for more info.