# Add character to string using VB6

Tags: vb6

Say I have an address like this:

```
Dim address as string
address= "1 The Street, London, LN11SD"
```

I want to add a space before the last three characters so the address looks like this (notice the space in the post code):

```
1 The Street, London, LN1 1SD
```

How can I do this? I have spent the last hour Googling this simple problem and I have found lots of examples of how to do this in VB.NET using string.Insert.  However, I cannot find any examples that talk about VB6 and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: Look up Left() and Mid() functions. Be careful with that approach though, because it won't be able to handle if you have a weird postcode, or if the original address is not formatted correctly, etc.

Comment: Also, your code as shown above is not valid syntax. The strings must be in double quotes.

Comment: read len() - 3 with left(), concat " ", concat the last 3 with right$()

Comment: VB6 does not support initializing a string variable on the variable declaration. So even adding quotes to the nominal initialize would result in a compile error.  This is not valid VB6 code - should this be tagged with VB.NET (which does support declaration initializing)?  (Even though the post mentions VB6 in lieu of VB.NET?)

Comment: @MarkL, I have updated the post   thanks

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - You have to take all the address variable and remove the last 3 characters using the Mid function
 
Step 2 - add the space
 
Step 3 - use the right function to get the last 3 characters

```
Dim address As String
address = "1 The Street, London, LN11SD"

address = Mid(address, 1, Len(address) - 3) & " " & Right(address, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplistically, you can do this:

```
Dim address as string
address = "1 The Street, London, LN11SD"

address = Left$(address, 25) & " " & Right$(address, 3)
```

That being said, I think you'd need a lot more logic to detect exactly where there was a missing space in a large set of addresses.

Comment: Using Left$ and Right$ is the way to go. But you need to detect the length of the string. Or even better use RegEx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747363/usage-of-regex-in-vb6

Comment: My real question would be, is it always just three characters?  That is what my last sentence was about, figuring a good way to detect where the space really needs to be.  Though perhaps my lack of knowledge on UK addresses is showing an the last segment is always 3 characters long?  Even then, the first step would be to check if the space was already present and skip the addition completely.